# Threading: doing processing in background of C++ Cinder app to keep the UI responsive

Tags: c++, image, background

I was happy to get my first C++ app working after a few hours of hacking this afternoon. The app trades the X-dimension for the time-dimension in a video.

- Example: http://www.flickr.com/photos/forresto/5489312991/
- Source: https://gist.github.com/849779

Any suggestions for how to optimize the source would be welcome, but I'm interested in how to do the image processing that I'm doing in `update()` in a way that doesn't make the app so unresponsive.

(Crossposted in libcinder forum: http://forum.libcinder.org/#Topic/23286000000669039 )

Comment: so do you still have a question? otherwise maybe mark it as solved. It still shows up in unanswered questions.

Comment: how? adding [SOLVED] to the title?

Comment: There is a box below... Add your edit as the answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems be threading. It works like this with Cinder:

```
void MyApp::setup()
{
  thread(&MyApp::processFrame, this);
}
void MyApp::processFrame()
{
  // TODO define mFrameTemp here
  // Copy to the texture which we'll actually render
  mFrame = mFrameTemp;
}
void MyApp::draw()
{
  if (mFrame)
    gl::draw(mFrame, mFrame.getBounds());
}
```